# display post tags on single.php inside loop

Tags: loop, array

I want to display the tags of the current post in the single.php and do the following:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="single_h"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
    <p class="single_subline"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subline', true) ?></p>
    <!-- everythings fine til here -->   
    <p class="single_tags"><?php echo wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); ?></p> 
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

and everything just works fine, except the `wp_get_post_tags` method. All I get displayed inside the `.single_tags` is the string `Array`.

I am new to wordpress and would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`the_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)?

Comment: @ChipBennett works! But don't get whats wrong with my approach! Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `Array` because that's exactly what [`wp_get_post_tags`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) returns; an array (and when you try and echo one in PHP it'll simply output `Array`).

As @Chip Bennet suggested, use [`the_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) instead, which outputs an HTML string.